# not install the Openni drivers onto my system

Tags: ros, openni, git, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers
cd drivers
make
```

then, not installed and displayed it

```
cd openni && make
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/drivers/openni'
git clone https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI.git build/openni
make[1]: git: Command not found
make[1]: *** [build/openni] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/rooroot/drivers/openni'
make: *** [openni_lib] Error2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35216/not-install-the-openni-drivers-onto-my-system/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This message:

> git: Command not found

suggests that git is not installed in your system... try this:

> sudo apt-get install git-core

Then try to do make again.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2